# MS-Access Database Locking when running a Insert Query via VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am creating a simple database. I have a functionality where i have simply created a Insert Into query an saved it in the database. what i want to do is, 
call that query in VBA code.

I have done following coding :

```
Private Sub Update_ISO_Review_Register()
  Dim dbs As DAO.Database

  Set dbs = CurrentDb

  dbs.Execute "Update_ISO_Review_Register_ApplicationData"

  dbs.Close
  Set dbs = Nothing
End Sub
```

The code works and it executes the query. Issue is that after that it locks the database and it gives the following error.

> You do not have exclusive access to the database at this time. if you
>   proceed to make changes, you may not be able to save them later.

The SQL for the `Update_ISO_Review_Register_ApplicationData` query is:

```
INSERT INTO     ISO_REVIEW_REGISTER ( SLTF_Ref, Brand, Application_No ) 
SELECT DISTINCT b.matter_No AS SLTF_Ref
                , b.Brand
                , b.CREDIT_APPLICATION_ID AS Application_No 
FROM            WBC_HFM_FileReveiw_Table AS a INNER JOIN WBC_HFM_Application_Table AS b ON 
                    a.CREDIT_APPLICATION_ID = b.CREDIT_APPLICATION_ID;
```

Any help ?

Comment: Without the SQL of that query, we can't know what's happening. At least remove the `dbs.Close`, `CurrentDb` is a reference to your current database connection, and you don't want to close that.

Comment: That is **not** locking the database; just the opposite.  It *needs* to lock the database but it cannot.

Comment: My query is below

Comment: INSERT INTO ISO_REVIEW_REGISTER ( SLTF_Ref, Brand, Application_No )
SELECT DISTINCT b.matter_No AS SLTF_Ref, b.Brand, b.CREDIT_APPLICATION_ID AS Application_No
FROM WBC_HFM_FileReveiw_Table AS a INNER JOIN WBC_HFM_Application_Table AS b ON a.CREDIT_APPLICATION_ID = b.CREDIT_APPLICATION_ID;

Comment: `dbs.Close` - don't. You never do this, except for DBs you explicitly opened with `OpenDatabase`.

Answer (score 1):

Would it work if you only do this:

```
Private Sub Update_ISO_Review_Register()    
    CurrentDb.Execute "Update_ISO_Review_Register_ApplicationData"        
End Sub
```

You can nicely live without these:

```
  Dim dbs As DAO.Database
  Set dbs = CurrentDb
  dbs.Close
  Set dbs = Nothing
```

especially set `set dbs = Nothing`, which is a local variable and "dies" after `End Sub`.