# ms-access If Else statement in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I keep on getting a syntax error when trying to run this on a VBA code in ms access. any thoughts why?

```
if (WBC_HFM_Application_Table.SETTLEMENT_DATE Is Null) Then 'No' Else 'Yes' as Funded
```

I tried to put "End If" at the end and also tried again before 'as' word but no luck.

Comment: Is that your whole query?

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at the [Immediate If function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3). BTW you cannot use ' to enclose strings in vba, you need ".

Comment: @PatrickHonorez I think the OP mixed vba and query, because it is not really vba either

Comment: What is `WBC_HFM_Application_Table` ? a form ?

Comment: Looking at your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50811072/ms-access-database-locking-when-running-a-insert-query-via-vba) `WBC_HFM_Application_Table` is the name of the table, so I guess `Settlement_Date` is a field in the table? You can't reference that way, for a start it wouldn't know which record you were talking about.  Is it a specific record you're looking at, or just if any record in the table is null - what are the parameters to get the correct record?

Answer (score 1):

This is some small example of the `If-Else-End If` logic:

```
If IsNull(WBC_HFM_Application_Table.SETTLEMENT_DATE) Then 
    Debug.Print "No" 
Else 
    Debug.Print "Yes"
End If
```

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth - noted, 10x :)